# Move cursor to specific point on screen using ncurses c++ (Linux)

Tags: c++, cursor, move, ncurses

i'd like to move the cursor to specific point on screen, but i can move logical point, but the cursor stay static on position.

How to do it work in c++ using ncurses ?

OBS.: i've tried to use move(y, x); but it doesn't works

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this case?

Comment: My cursor [] stay in a old position after use move. 

But i tried now **mvaddstr(2,2,"");** and it works.

Answer (score 1):

From the move(y,x) [man page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_move.3x.html):

> This routine does not move the physical cursor of the terminal until refresh is called.

Did you call [refresh()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html) after calling move(y,x)